# Magento Enterprise install Extension

Tags: magento-enterprise, extensions

Maybe I´m just standing somewhere next to me today but I can´t find a way to install an extension in my Magento Enterprise Edition right now. In my Backend -->System--> I can´t find Magento Connect anymore.
Could it be that another Admin set it hidden for me or what could be the reason?

I got the .tgz file but can´t get it to install on my Magento version. I´m using Magento Enterprise 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most logical reason is another admin user removed it from the view. I would try logging in as a super admin.

Especially with a Enterprise client, you shouldn't be downloading extensions from Magento Connect directly. You should really bring in extensions with version control and first test in a staging environment before going to production.

You also want to watch out with version compatibility. You say you are on Magento EE 1.7, which was released in 2010. Looking at Magento Connect, there are only 33 free extensions for that version.

[image]